# How to export only certain column from selected feature to csv file in QGIS using python code

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have selected features in QGIS, I want to export only two columns from the selected features to a csv file automatically using python code. I have tried the following code:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer() 
selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures() 

for i in selected_features:
    idx = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('name')
    uv = layer.dataProvider().uniqueValues(idx)

for i in uv:
    if i:
        print str(i)
```

Comment: What is the code you have tried?

Comment: above is the code i have tried. when i tried this code it prints all the details instead of only selected features deatils. what i did wrong?

Comment: This will give you a csv file with all selected records and fields QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, "E:\\myfile.csv", "utf-8", None, "CSV", onlySelected=True) perhaps you can define the fields to include with the dataSourceOption

Comment: Should `uv = layer.dataProvider().uniqueValues(idx)` not be `uv = selected_features.dataProvider().uniqueValues(idx)`?

Answer (score 4):

You can write defined columns from selected features in a csv file in this way:

```
import csv
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.selectedFeatures() # Here you get a list of selected features

columns=['id','country','city'] #here you write the columns you want to export. Or use a list with the columns

# Here you write for every selected feature a list with only the columsn you have defined
 filteredFields = []    
 for feature in features:
    attrs = [feature[column] for column in columns]
    filteredFields.append(attrs)

# Now you can write the filterField list with the list of selected attributes into your csv file.
with open(C:\\test.csv, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',') #as delimiter you can use other character as well
    for field in filteredFields:
        writer.writerow(field)
```

The [QGIS documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-vector-layer) also provides information on how to iterate over the features of a layer.